# Jensen's Inequality

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value, jensen-inequality

For arbitrary α and β satisfying 0 < α ≤ β, use Jensen’s inequality to find a bound of the form 
E[|X|$^α$] ≤ f(E[|X|$^β$]) for some function f.

Doesn't this bound follow naturally from the fact that α ≤ β without having to apply Jensen's inequality?

That is, since α ≤ β,

E[|X|$^α$] $\le$ E[|X|$^β$]

What am I missing here?

Comment: $(1/2)^1 > (1/2)^2$.

Comment: Thanks, I was assuming α, β > 1.

Comment: I think you mean that you were assuming $X \geq 1$?

Comment: Yes, sorry that's what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Jensen's inequality tells you that if $\ f\ $ is convex then $\ f(E(Y))\le E(f(Y))\ $. If you take $\ Y=|X|^\alpha\ $, can you find a strictly increasing convex function $\ f\ $ such that $\ f(Y)=
|X|^\beta\ $?