# Applying Jensen's inequality to find a bound

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value, jensen-inequality

I'm not sure how to begin with this question, apart from writing some basic relationships based on Jensen's inequality.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

For arbitrary α and β satisfying 0 < α ≤ β, use Jensen’s inequality to find a bound of the form 
E[|X|$^α$] ≤ f(E[|X|$^β$]) for some function f.

Attempt at a solution:

E[|X|$^α$] $\ge$ (E[|X|])$^α$ 
E[|X|$^β$] $\ge$ (E[|X|])$^β$

f(E[|X|$^α$]) $\le$ E[f(|X|$^α$)] 
f(E[|X|$^β$]) $\le$ E[f(|X|$^β$)]

Comment: It would have been polite to link to your prior attempt https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3850553/147357

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$E|X|^{\alpha}\leq (E|X|^{\beta})^{\alpha /\beta}$ by Jensen's inequality applied to the convex function $g(t)= t^{\beta /\alpha }$. Indeed $(E|X|^{\alpha})^{\beta /\alpha} =g(E|X|^{\alpha})) \leq (Eg(|X|^{\alpha}))$ which gives the inequality. Hence we can take $f(x)=x^{\alpha  /\beta}$.

Comment: Thanks - shouldn't it be >= though by Jensen's inequality?

Comment: @apostrophic I have edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks again - I realized I'm mistaken so I appreciate your providing a new answer.